# How to get content-type (or variable type) for a particular set of data in python?

Tags: python, types

Assuming you have a dictionary like the one below, what would be the best way to get the variable type for each of the items of the dictionary?

```
dict = {}
dict['item1'] = 'the book is on the table'
dict['item2'] = '2014-03-14 22:10:00'
dict['item3'] = 'https://foo.com/bar.jpg'
dict['item4'] = '23449'
dict['item5'] = 'True'
dict['itemN'] = '...'
```

The desired output would be:

```
 - item1 -> string
 - item2 -> date
 - item3 -> string(url)
 - item4 -> number
 - item5 -> boolean
 - itemN -> ...
```

Comment: You can use type(x) to get the type of variable x. As stated, the type of all values in your problem is str. You need to parse the strings into the desired objects in order to use the type() builtin.

Comment: If your string format is fixed, consider using `regexp`. You may find what you want in [Regular Expression Examples](http://wiki.tcl.tk/989).:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, never use `dict` as the name of a variable, it shadows the builtin (yes, I'm such a nazy :-).

Use literal_eval from the ast module.

```
from ast import literal_eval
from dateutil import parser

def guess_type(v):
    if v == '...':
        return 'Ellipsis'
    try:
        return type(literal_eval(v)).__name__
    except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
        try:
            return type(parser.parse(v)).__name__
        except ValueError:
            pass
        return 'string'

data = [
    'the book is on the table',
    '2014-03-14 22:10:00',
    'https://foo.com/bar.jpg',
    '23449',
    'True',
    'None',
    '{"foo": 1}',
    '{"foo"}',
    '...',
]

for i, item in enumerate(data):
    print('- Item{} -> {}'.format(i+1, guess_type(item)))
```

By all means avoid the `eval` advice from the other answer, because it is a huge security liability (consider the consequences of using eval on a string like `"__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')"` for example).

Result:

```
- Item1 -> string
- Item2 -> datetime
- Item3 -> string
- Item4 -> int
- Item5 -> bool
- Item6 -> NoneType
- Item7 -> dict
- Item8 -> string
- Item9 -> Ellipsis
```

Detecting special strings like URLs is left as an exercise for the reader (perhaps a good job for regular expressions).